# How to remove items contains a substring but not another substring

Tags: java

There is a file with the structure Book_position1_positon2_position3:

Book_unknow_unknow_unknow

Book_unknow_1_2

Book_unknow_unknow_2

Book_unknow_1_unknow

Book_EU_1_2

I want to remove all the items with at least one unknow at position2 and position3, but keep the one with unknow at position1.

therefore the filtered result should be:

Book_unknow_1_2

Book_EU_1_2

my code is:

```
 Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Book>> iter = books.entrySet().iterator();
 while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Book> entry = iter.next();
        if(entry.getKey().contains("_UNKNOW")) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```

unfortunately, this code will remove all the 'unknow' items, how to keep Book_unknow_1_2 still there?

Comment: It's spelled "unknown"

Comment: Try parsing the data first, splitting at `_`. This gives you four components, so that you can write dedicated logic dealing with each component.

Comment: split by underline _ and check the strings at index 2 and 3

Comment: note: "UNKNOWN" is not the same as "unknown"... convert the string to lower case (or upper) to stay case-insensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Book>> iter = books.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry<String, Book> entry = iter.next();
    if ( entry.getKey().matches("(.+_){2,}unknown.*") )
    {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage the String.split() method to check the value only at certain positions. For instance (code not tested):

```
public boolean shouldRemove(String s) {
    String[] parts = s.split("_");
    if (parts.length > 2 && parts[2].equals("unknown")) {
        return false;
    }
    if (parts.length > 3 && parts[3].equals("unknown")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think the logic is almost completely "the wrong way round". Conditions should be: If 1 unknown: no remove. If 2 or 3 unknown: remove. Otherwise: no remove.

Comment: Seems youre right... I wonder whether I should rename the method or change the return values xD

Comment: It is unimportant whether 1 is unknown or not, see OP.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto exactly! "should be ... Book_unknow_1_2"  see "unknow"  at position 1